# How to get api username and password for using jet.com APIs

Tags: jet.com-apis

I'm integrating jet.com APIs. the very first step is to generate token.
for this i need API user as username and secret as password.
don't know where to get API user and secret..

Example given: 
https://developer.jet.com/security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve your user and secret keys in the "API" Tab on the left hand nav of https://partner.jet.com/.

You can generate your token by serving a POST Request to https://merchant-api.jet.com/api/token with your secret and user.